# PHP Syntax: "or" in "If" Statement

Tags: php

hello I just wanted to check and see if this would be correct PHP syntax:

```
if ($input == "DeOnTRAY96@localhost"){
echo"
Projects: 1"?>
<br>
<?php     
echo"
Admin: yes
";

}
elseif ($input == NULL){
die("Please enter password.");
}else{
header("Location:Invalidpassword.php");
exit;
}
```

Right where is says

```
if($input == "DeOnTRAY96@localhost"){
```

Could I put

```
if($input == "DeOnTRAY96@localhost" or "somethingelse"){
```

And still have it work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want

```
if($input == "DeOnTRAY96@localhost" or "somethingelse"){
```

You want

```
if($input == "DeOnTRAY96@localhost" or $input == "somethingelse"){
```

I might suggest using `===` instead of `==` in this case, as you'd like a type sensitive comparison.

Additionally, for `$input == NULL` you should use `is_null($input)`. Null is weird in most programming languages, so language specific functions for testing are usually the way to go (rather than comparison)

Comment: Ok thanks I need to see if you could do that because i wanted to have 2 options that you could type into the password box

Comment: The `in_array()` suggestion made in another response would come in handy then.

Answer (score 0):

OR syntax in PHP:

```
if($var == 'something' || $var == 'something else')
{
  //do something
}
```

For reference:

`||` means OR

`&&` means AND

Answer (score 0):

For a more future-proof solution, consider [`in_array`](http://php.net/in-array). I use it for as few as two options, if there's even the slightest chance there may be more added.

```
if( in_array($input, ["DeOnTRAY96@localhost", "somethingelse"]))
```

Once you get to four or more options, it's probably better to do something more like:

```
$whitelist = [
      "DeOnTRAY96@localhost"
    , "somethingelse"
    , "anotheroption"
    , "too many options to do inline!"
];
if( in_array($input, $whitelist))
```